# R: Count all combinations in a list of strings (Specific Order)

Tags: r, count, combinations, sapply, strsplit

I am trying to count all sequences in a large list of characters delimetered by ">" but only the combinations that are directly next to each other.

e.g. given the character vector:

```
[1]Social>PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch>OrganicSearch>OrganicSearch>OrganicSearch
[2]Referral>Referral>Referral
```

I can run the following line to retrieve all combinations with of 2 characters:

```
split_fn <- sapply(p , strsplit , split = ">", perl=TRUE)

split_fn <- sapply(split_fn, function(x) paste(head(x,-1) , tail(x,-1) , sep = ">") )
```

Returns:

```
[[1]]

 [1] "Social>PaidSearch"           "PaidSearch>PaidSearch"       "PaidSearch>PaidSearch"       "PaidSearch>PaidSearch"       "PaidSearch>PaidSearch"      
 [6] "PaidSearch>PaidSearch"       "PaidSearch>PaidSearch"       "PaidSearch>PaidSearch"       "PaidSearch>PaidSearch"       "PaidSearch>PaidSearch"      
[11] "PaidSearch>OrganicSearch"    "OrganicSearch>OrganicSearch" "OrganicSearch>OrganicSearch"

[[2]]

[1] "Referral>Referral" "Referral>Referral"
```

Which is all possible 2 character sequences in my data (splits in order)

I know want to have all possible outcomes of 3 characters.

e.g.

```
"Social>PaidSearch>PaidSearch" "PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch"..."Referral>Referral>Referral"
```

Tried to use

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(p, split = ">"), function(i) combn(sort(i), 3, paste, collapse='>')))
```

But it returns all combinations including those that aren't directly following.

I also don't want it to return combinations of the last value in row one with the first value in row 2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with creating some data:

```r
set.seed(1)

data <- lapply(1:3, function(i) sample(LETTERS[1:3], rpois(1, 6), re = T))
data <- sapply(data, paste, collapse = ">")

data
#> [1] "B>B>C>A"           "C>B>B>A>A>A>C>B>C" "C>C>B>C>C>A"
```

Given the problem, it makes sense to think of these data as a list of
vectors that we get after splitting the elements by the delimiter `>`:

```r
strsplit(data, ">")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "B" "B" "C" "A"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "C" "B" "B" "A" "A" "A" "C" "B" "C"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "C" "C" "B" "C" "C" "A"
```

Now, the core of the problem is to find all consecutive sequences of a given
length from a single vector. Once we can do that, it's simple to apply over
the list of data that we have; transforming back to the delimited format will
also be simple.

With that goal in mind, we can then make a function for extracting the
sequences; here we just loop over each element and extract
all sequences of the given length to a list:

```r
seqs <- function(x, length = 2) {
  if (length(x) < length)
    return(NULL)
  k <- length - 1
  lapply(seq_len(length(x) - k), function(i) x[i:(i + k)])
}
```

We can now just apply the function accross the data after
splitting the delimited characters into vectors to get the result. We also need an additional `sapply` with `paste` to transform the data back into the delimited format that we started with:

```r
lapply(strsplit(data, ">"), function(x) {
  sapply(seqs(x, 3), paste, collapse = ">")
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "B>B>C" "B>C>A"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "C>B>B" "B>B>A" "B>A>A" "A>A>A" "A>A>C" "A>C>B" "C>B>C"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "C>C>B" "C>B>C" "B>C>C" "C>C>A"
```

---

Further, to get sequences of multiple lengths at the same time, we can add another layer of iteration:

```r
lapply(strsplit(data, ">"), function(x) {
  unlist(sapply(c(2, 3), function(n) {
    sapply(seqs(x, n), paste, collapse = ">")
  }))
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "B>B"   "B>C"   "C>A"   "B>B>C" "B>C>A"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] "C>B"   "B>B"   "B>A"   "A>A"   "A>A"   "A>C"   "C>B"   "B>C"  
#>  [9] "C>B>B" "B>B>A" "B>A>A" "A>A>A" "A>A>C" "A>C>B" "C>B>C"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "C>C"   "C>B"   "B>C"   "C>C"   "C>A"   "C>C>B" "C>B>C" "B>C>C" "C>C>A"
```

Created on 2018-05-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: That works perfect. I have a further question which is just to make my life a bit easier so I don't have to do any merging later. Is there an easy modification to this code that would allow me to get both sequences with 2 characters and 3 characters. i.e. "B>B", "B>C", "B>B>C" etc.

Comment: Hmm.. Sure: that just requires an additional `sapply` layer in the end. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JamieAllan No problem, and welcome to SO! As your problem is solved, you could also [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I have just tried to increase my list size as it won't let me go more than 10. In fact, I have 24,000,000 rows that I eventually need to apply the code on. The code in my original post was able to cycle through all 24M rows and returned a table tallying all sequences. There is a definitive number of sequences depending on the order of the model I am using. In the first case (2 chars) there is 81 possible combinations. In the second case (2-3 chars) there is 810 possible combinations. Exponentially increasing with the higher order. I assumed this code would work but I guess not on a large scale

Comment: Returns Error:  _Error in seq_len(length(x) - k) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer_

Comment: That happens because there are data that are shorter than the sequence length that you are looking for; that case needs to be handled separately in the `seqs` function: see the edited version.

Comment: Ah...Yes I just realized I had rows with only 1 character so there was no delimiter etc. Thanks again, I will accept the answer now

Answer (score 1):

Using the `stringr` package (or regex in general).

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(p, "(\\w+)>(\\w+)>(\\w+)")
```

With overlap, but the code could be simplified.

```
str_extract_all_overlap <- function (x) {
  extractions <- character()
  x_curr <- x
  extr <- str_extract(x_curr, "(\\w+)>(\\w+)>(\\w+)")
  i = 1
  while (!is.na(extr)) {
    extractions[i] <- extr 
    x_curr <- str_replace(x_curr, "\\w+", replacement = "")
    extr <- str_extract(x_curr, "(\\w+)>(\\w+)>(\\w+)")
    i = i + 1
  }
  return(extractions)
}

lapply(p, str_extract_all_overlap)
```

Comment: I think there should be 12 extracted chunks when accounting for overlaps. This only gets the 4 discrete parts with no overlap.

Comment: This is a good start. However, thelatemail is correct, this only returns 5 discrete parts, 4 for the first character and 1 for the 2nd. I need to have the overlapping occurances too.

Comment: Addressed in the edit, but there is probably a simpler solution with fewer lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

You could also adapt the `paste`-command in your second `sapply` to:

```
paste(head(x,-2), head(tail(x,-1),-1), tail(x,-2) , sep = ">")
```

Your full code should now look like:

```
split_fn <- sapply(p , strsplit , split = ">", USE.NAMES = FALSE)

split_fn <- sapply(split_fn, function(x) paste(head(x,-2), head(tail(x,-1),-1), tail(x,-2), sep = ">") )
```

The result:

```
> split_fn
[[1]]
 [1] "Social>PaidSearch>PaidSearch"              "PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch"          "PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch"         
 [4] "PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch"          "PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch"          "PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch"         
 [7] "PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch"          "PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch"          "PaidSearch>PaidSearch>PaidSearch"         
[10] "PaidSearch>PaidSearch>OrganicSearch"       "PaidSearch>OrganicSearch>OrganicSearch"    "OrganicSearch>OrganicSearch>OrganicSearch"

[[2]]
[1] "Referral>Referral>Referral"
```

Comment: Nice. The head(tail(x,-1),-1) line is what I was initially looking for. I was trying to modify head and tail seperately but didn't think of that. However, the solution above is a much cleaner way and gets extra information which I was going to find by merging this with my previous results. Thanks for the input